# SQL Certificate error while creating new certificate

Tags: sql-server, certificate

I'm getting the following error, while adding

> A certificate with name 'Principal_Cert' already exists or this
>   certificate already has been added to the database.

Script:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE Principal_Cert
    AUTHORIZATION Principal_User
    FROM FILE = 'D:\Cert01.cer';
GO
```

But when I do a `select * from sys.certificates` it doesn't show me an entry for `Principal_Cert`

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by redoing all config which involves dropping and recreation of logins and endpoints.